# Cmake Regenerate on variable change

Tags: c++, mercurial, cmake

Y Part:

I've got a CMake macro that runs an external program and creates project specific variables. What I'd like to have CMake do is to run this script on every build, check if the variables have changed, and iff they have (to prevent full project rebuild when it has not), regenerate a CONFIGURE_FILE header...I'm not really sure how to do this though. (Add custom target rebuilds the header file every time and can't call macros, same with Add Custom Command).

X part:

So I've written the following script for pulling hg version information for use in a c++ project:

```
macro (ReadProjectRevisionStatus)
exec_program(hg ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ARGS paths OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS)
message(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS}}")
if (NOT(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS STREQUAL ""))

string(REPLACE "\n" ";" ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS})

foreach(HGPATH ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS})
string(SUBSTRING "${HGPATH}" 0 10 HGPATHSTART)
if (HGPATHSTART MATCHES "default = ")
string(LENGTH "${HGPATH}" HGPATHLENGTH)
math(EXPR HGSUBLEN "${HGPATHLENGTH}-10")
string(SUBSTRING "${HGPATH}" 10 ${HGSUBLEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR)
endif()
endforeach()

endif()

if (NOT ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR)
message(WARNING "No remote repository set. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
else()
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} ARGS status RETURN_VALUE HGREMOTESTATUSVALUE OUTPUT_VARIABLE NUL)
if (NOT HGREMOTESTATUSVALUE EQUAL 0)
message(WARNING "Cannot connect to remote repository at ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()
endif()

#Identify changeset
exec_program(hg ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ARGS "id" "-i" OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE)

if (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE MATCHES ".*\\+")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Node is dirty. Will generate temporary version number...")
set (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGDIRTY 1)
string(LENGTH ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} HGHASHLEN)
MATH(EXPR HGHASHLEN "${HGHASHLEN}-1")
string(SUBSTRING ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} 0 ${HGHASHLEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE)
endif()
#check if remote repository contains changeset
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}"
RETURN_VALUE HGREMOTEHASCHANGESET
OUTPUT_VARIABLE NUL)
if (NOT HGREMOTEHASCHANGESET EQUAL 0)
message(WARNING "Remote repository ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} does not have changeset ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} "--template" "{latesttag}"
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION)

MESSAGE(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION}")

exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} 
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} "--template" "{latesttagdistance}"
 OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER)

if (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGDIRTY)
MATH(EXPR ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER}+1")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}+")
endif()

MESSAGE(STATUS "Version=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}")
endmacro()
```

And I currently call it like this.

```
ReadProjectRevisionStatus()
CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/main.h)
```

Where main.h.in is:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <string>

const std::string ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION = "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION}";
const std::string ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER = "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER}";
const std::string ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE = "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}";

const std::string ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_SHORT_VERSION = 
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION+"."+
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER;

const std::string ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_VERSION = 
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_SHORT_VERSION + "." +
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE;

#endif
```

What I'd like to do is run this macro on every build command (I can use ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET and then set the variables instead of reading them from the project), but I only want to regenerate main.h if the variables have changed (to prevent unnecessary recompilation).

EDIT: Working solution

Made a HGVersion.CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

macro (ReadProjectRevisionStatus)
message(STATUS PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

exec_program(hg ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ARGS paths OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS)
message(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS}}")
if (NOT(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS STREQUAL ""))

string(REPLACE "\n" ";" ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS})

foreach(HGPATH ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGPATHS})
string(SUBSTRING "${HGPATH}" 0 10 HGPATHSTART)
if (HGPATHSTART MATCHES "default = ")
string(LENGTH "${HGPATH}" HGPATHLENGTH)
math(EXPR HGSUBLEN "${HGPATHLENGTH}-10")
string(SUBSTRING "${HGPATH}" 10 ${HGSUBLEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR)
endif()
endforeach()

endif()

if (NOT ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR)
message(WARNING "No remote repository set. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
else()
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} ARGS status RETURN_VALUE HGREMOTESTATUSVALUE OUTPUT_VARIABLE NUL)
if (NOT HGREMOTESTATUSVALUE EQUAL 0)
message(WARNING "Cannot connect to remote repository at ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()
endif()

#Identify changeset
exec_program(hg ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ARGS "id" "-i" OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE)

if (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE MATCHES ".*\\+")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Node is dirty. Will generate temporary version number...")
set (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGDIRTY 1)
string(LENGTH ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} HGHASHLEN)
MATH(EXPR HGHASHLEN "${HGHASHLEN}-1")
string(SUBSTRING ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} 0 ${HGHASHLEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE)
endif()
#check if remote repository contains changeset
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}"
RETURN_VALUE HGREMOTEHASCHANGESET
OUTPUT_VARIABLE NUL)
if (NOT HGREMOTEHASCHANGESET EQUAL 0)
message(WARNING "Remote repository ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} does not have changeset ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}. Will use current direcoty for build number, but this value may be inaccurate.")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} "--template" "{latesttag}"
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION)

MESSAGE(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION}")

exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR} 
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE} "--template" "{latesttagdistance}"
 OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER)

if (${PROJECT_NAME}_HGDIRTY)
MATH(EXPR ${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER}+1")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}+")
endif()

MESSAGE(STATUS "Version=${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGMAJORMINORVERSION}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGBUILDNUMBER}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGHASHCODE}")
endmacro()
message(STATUS "GETTING HG VERSION")
ReadProjectRevisionStatus()
CONFIGURE_FILE(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.h.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/main.h)
```

In the main cmake file

```
add_custom_target(
${PROJECT_NAME}_hg_version_target
 DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.h.in
 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
 ARGS -DPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
 -DPROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
 -DPROJECT_BINARY_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
 -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/HGVersion.CMake")
```

and

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_hg_version_target)

Works but seems...real messy. Anyone got something better?

Answer (score 1):

If something during the build process determines contents of a file to be generated, you cannot generate that file with configure_file, because configure_file operates during the configuration phase and not at build time. This is a design choice by CMake.

In your case you really have to use add_custom_command and add_custom_target to generate that file during the build process, as you found out already.

For your proposed solution there might be a chance to simplify this a bit. As you are generating a C/C++ header file, the CMake internal parser should be able to automatically discover which of your usual source code files depend on main.h. So it should be sufficient to provide a custom command with add_custom_command, which declares as its OUTPUT the main.h file it will generate. CMake should call this command automatically once it tries to build a target where one of the C/C++ files depends on it. So you probably do not need the custom target and manually declared dependency.

Comment: I tried that: however, CMake does not know that it needs to check the version on **every** build: if there is a main.h it will not regenerate main.h. Only add_custom_target (with no output) will run every time.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about that. Then you did everything in line with the CMake concepts. I don't think there is a non-hacked way to simplify this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna wrap the whole mess in a macro. Thanks though.